# Store a MySQL column to an array then print in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am trying to store a column named **imgPath** from a table named **images** in my database to an array in PHP. Then I want to print it out so I can see that it worked. You can see what the table looks like below:

[image: From the table **images**]

Below is the code I am using to not succeed lol:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'userdatabase', 'PASSData', 'sftdatabase');
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT imgPath FROM images"); 

$result_array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row['imgPath'];
}
print_r($result_array);
```

I have tried using `print_r($result);` right before creating the array and I get:

[image: This]

How can I get the path? (**example:** *img/art/10/download.jpg*)

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` != `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple mistake,

Change,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

To,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Notice the `i` for `mysqli` is missing in the first.

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'userdatabase', 'PASSData', 'sftdatabase');
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT imgPath FROM images"); 

$result_array = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row['imgPath'];
}

print_r($result_array);
```